# ADB not responding with Android Studio on Windows 8

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, adb

I have already seen & tried all existing questions related to `ADB not responding` and yet I have been unable to fix my problem.

This is the message I keep getting in Android Studio:

[image: ADB Not REsponding]

And here are the running processes in my Task Manager:

[image: My TaskManager]

Can someone guide me as to what I can do in this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On of the running apps on your PC is preventing ADB from functioning properly. In my case, I shut off Norton, Bluestacks, Kies, and then ADB worked properly. In your case it looks like the `Device Association Framework` that seems to be interfering with ADB.

ADB normally works well in conjunction with ONE application at a time: either Android Studio or something else.

Also, update your SDK.

Comment: I have tried stoppin avira and other applications but still I am getting the same error and in the update section it is showing that you are already having the latest version of Android SDK :(

Comment: also try restarting your computer after you have disabled all these things

Answer (score 0):

It seems your SDK version is too old. Upate your SDK version.